# What factors affect the critical temperature of a material?

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter, temperature, superconductivity, phase-transition

I recently started learning electricity in A level physics and came across the concept of superconductivity. I find this very intriguing due to its capabilities.

My questions are:

- What are the factors which affect the critical temperature for superconductivity of a material?
- Based on this, is it possible to create new materials which have a high critical temperature?
- Currently, what is the highest critical temperature of a material?

Answer (score 1):

The electrical resistance arises due to collisions of charge carriers with the Atoms of the conductor. These collisions occur especially due to thermal Brownian Motion. If the conductor is cooled, the thermal Brownian Motion fades away and, depending on the material composition of the conductor, collisions go to Zero. Material composition, but also the external pressure influences the critical temperature of a material.

Since Generations of Research, scientists try to find new superconducting materials and aim for a higher critical temperature. Electrical Energy is also wasted in the wires and if we could find a superconductor that works on room temperature, we can save a lot of Energy.

It was found that the material consisting of mercury, Barium, Copper, Calcium and Oxygen ($HgBa_2Ca_2Cu_3O_{8+\delta}$) has the highest critical temperature (found since 1993). This critical temperature can be up to 138K.

Comment: just to add: if one apply pressure on superconducting material Tc might rise up. For example Tc of H2S is 190K under 200 GPa pressure.

Comment: @pan91, nobody in their right mind would want to use H2S for a superconductor.  That molecule is absolutely DEADLY and FAST if it is inhaled at more than a very small concentration, meaning that if the cooling system for such a conductor failed, the owners of that system would soon be dead.